# Two similar code constructs but one does not work

Tags: android, kotlin

The following are two blocks of code that should essentially do the same thing. But the second one does not execute the onEditorAction while the first one does. What is it about the second one that is different that prevents it from executing the code? NOTE: Only one of these is present in the code and not both.

```
// This one works    
this.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH){
            mOnRunSearchCallback()
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }

// This one does not work
    this.setOnEditorActionListener(object : TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
        override fun onEditorAction(v: TextView, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                mOnRunSearchCallback()
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second example with this

```
this.setOnEditorActionListener(object : TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
      override fun onEditorAction(v: TextView?, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
             return true;
      }
 })
```

Basically, you have wrong arguments type for v and event both `v` & `event` are nullable.

Comment: You're right. I guess you can't rely entirely on the copy/paste from Java to Kotlin. I pasted the Java version from a stackoverflow solution. Mind you, I like the shorter version better. There's also no need to add the question marks to indicate nullable.